# What is the most powerful solid rocket fuel (highest isp) and it's combustion temperature

Tags: fuel, temperature, solid-fuel, srb

I wanted to know what the most power full solid rocket fuel is.  I do not mean theoretical once like metallic hydrogen.

Are solid rocket fuel mixtures prepared in a non-ideal mixture? In other words, do they have to deviate from their stoichiometric ratio in order to have operable temperature and stay under the constraints of the material (or the nozzle is preferably made from an ablative material?)

I want to know the combustion temperatures of solid fuels.  Are there any tables or graphs which compare different solid fuels with their respective combustion temperatures?

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration. Please read our [about] and [ask] pages to understand what we need in a question post, and then edit your post to focus on 1 specific question. As it stands, it is unclear what you are wanting..

Comment: ISP 295.2 according to this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_rocket_engines). 297 according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(rocket_stage)). There could be others.